# conditional member function declaration based on variadic template length

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to define a different set of member functions in my class based on the length of the class's variadic template. Is this possible? For example is something like this possible?

```
template<class T, std::size_t... T2>
class S {
   public:
      #ifdef SIZE_OF_T2_GREATER_THAN_ZERO
         void f1(params1);
      #else
         void f2(params2);
      #endif
};
```

So if the length of `T2...` is greater than zero I want function `f1` defined while if there are no parameters in `T2...` I want some function `f2` defined. Is this possible?

Comment: there is the `sizeof...` operator. Have you tried/do you know it? I can elaborate into an answer.

Comment: I am not sure how to use sizeof... in this context. Some advice would be appreciated

Comment: Do you really need the one member to not exist at all, or is it okay if it's a function that can never be selected by overload resolution ,and therefore never instantiated?

Comment: I am not familiar with how overload resolution would work. I guess I would be interested in knowing about both ways, to decide what works best for my problem....

Comment: Do `f1` and `f2` have different names deliberately?

Comment: yes f1 and f2 are completely different functions with different names and different parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the member function templated based on `sizeof...()` applied to `T2...`

```
template<std::size_t L = sizeof...(T2)>
```

You can conditionally compile the functions using `std::enable_if`, as in:

```
template<class T, std::size_t... T2>
struct my_struct{
    template<std::size_t L = sizeof...(T2)>
    typename std::enable_if<L!=0, void>::type f1()
    {
        std::cout<< "this class has T2...\n";
    }

    template<std::size_t L = sizeof...(T2)>
    typename std::enable_if<L==0, void>::type f2()
    {
        std::cout<< "this class has nooooo T2\n";
    }
};
```

I`ve made a working example at http://cpp.sh/6jskq

Comment: Why do you need SFINAE here? SFINAE is useful to exclude a function from overload resolution. Here the functions have different names, so no overload resolution. To prevent a function from being called, `static_assert` seems to be a more appropriate tool.

Comment: @Evg I was not sure, tanks. Removed from the answer.

Comment: You're still using SFINAE, though. My point (that may be wrong, hence the question) is that here `static_assert` is better that SFINAE.

Comment: You're still using SFINAE.

Comment: Well, if anyone can improve the answers about it, please edit =p

Comment: @Evg isn't overload resolution basicly  means when we let the compiler to choose the most appropriate function? so in his example compiler is choosing the right function to call based on whats passed. isn't it? so why SFINAE would be a problem here im confused.

Comment: @Evg I understood your point about the `static_assert` reading your answer, booth approaches seems ok to me.

Comment: @Yucel_K, it is not a problem, but there is no space for overload resolution here: there exist only one `f1` and one `f2`.

Answer (score 2):

Basic idea:

```
template<std::size_t size_of_t2, class T>
struct Base
{ 
    void f1(params1);
};

template<class T>
struct Base<0, T>
{
    void f2(params2);
};

template<class T, std::size_t... T2>
struct S : Base<sizeof...(T2), T>
{ };
```

Alternatively, you could have both `f1` and `f2` present in `S` and then guard their usage by `static_assert` (note that member functions of a class template are not instantiated unless they are used):

```
template<class T, std::size_t... T2>
struct S
{
    void f1(params1)
    { 
        static_assert(sizeof...(T2) > 0);
        ...
    }

    void f2(params2)
    { 
        static_assert(sizeof...(T2) == 0);
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Your functions are SFINAE unfriendly.

Comment: @PasserBy, what do you mean by that?